# Openlayers : unable to print / export pdf's with google maps while osm works

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers, angular-openlayers

I am able to print the pdf while refering to the openlayers export to pdf example, https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html, when open street map is set as background is working fine but when I set google map as background it doesn't work it gives an empty canvas.

I have a google map created like this

```
const mapProperties = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.902782, 12.496366),
      zoom: 5,
      tilt: 0,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      maxZoom: 80,
      minZoom: 1,
      disableDefaultUI: true
     };
    this._googleMap = new google.maps.Map(mapsElement, mapProperties);
    var query = ".ol-layer canvas,.tiff,.**google_map**";
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(query),
```

using openlayers example I'm trying printing the google map using the class name but it is not rendered maybe because of the cross origin, now the question is how to set cross origin anonymous in the google maps.

Comment: It will only export layers with cross origin access

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: added the code now

Comment: Google maps is not OpenLayers, you cannot access the canvas because the map is inside an iframe.  It is possible to access Google tiles directly in Openlayers e.g. `new XYZ({url: 'https://mt{0-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', crossOrigin: ''})` but using them in that way contravenes Google's terms of service.